# How to add meta description in hybris?

Tags: meta-tags, meta, sap-commerce-cloud, meta-title

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7feW.jpg)I can see the place where I can add meta title but unable to see any meta description column.

Answer (score 3):

You can debug the `ProductPageController` there you can see how metaDescription being set. In Hybris OOTB(I'm referring 6.7), meta description being set using product description. So you need to check the same in your codebase. If you haven't customized that part so far then tries setting product description and check.

**ProductPageController**

```
final String metaKeywords = MetaSanitizerUtil.sanitizeKeywords(productData.getKeywords());
final String metaDescription = MetaSanitizerUtil.sanitizeDescription(productData.getDescription());
setUpMetaData(model, metaKeywords, metaDescription);
```

**AbstractPageController**

```
protected void setUpMetaData(final Model model, final String metaKeywords, final String metaDescription)
{
    final List<MetaElementData> metadata = new LinkedList<>();
    metadata.add(createMetaElement("keywords", metaKeywords));
    metadata.add(createMetaElement("description", metaDescription));
    model.addAttribute("metatags", metadata);
}
```