# Add custom META tags to pages in Hybris

Tags: meta-tags, sap-commerce-cloud

I need to add custom meta tags to a Hybris site, yet I can't find anything in HMC (the site is based on version 6.5) or Backoffice. Is there any way to do it on live site without changes to the code or are code changes necessary for this?

Comment: Yes, you can set meta keywords & description through HMC/Backoffice, I'll answer soon.. By the time you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56071106/2478134), you'll get the idea.

Comment: @HybrisHelp Yes, I know about keywords and description. This is not what I am looking for.  I need to add custom meta tags, e.g. `<meta http-equiv="abcd" content="1234"/>` and `<meta name="my-custom-tag" content="my-custom-value"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to do it on live site without changes to the code or
>   are code changes necessary for this?

As per my knowledge, there is no way to add custom meta-type without changing the code. You can only add meta keywords and meta description through back-office.

For `<meta http-equiv="abcd" content="1234"/>`, you can add it to **master.tag**
 and for `<meta name="my-custom-tag" content="my-custom-value"/>` you can again hardcode in master.tag or get it populated from some item type by changing server side code. 
Refer createMetaElement method of **AbstractPageController**, **UiExperienceMetadataViewHandler** and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56071106/2478134)

Comment: Thanks. This is what I figured. I did update `master.tag` with specific tags before, but it's fixed if done on its own. I want to allow my business users to add/change tags as required, so I'll need to effectively create a new type for these tags and then make the necessary change in WCMS to allow associating a collection of tags against each page or page template.  Will be quite a bit of work.

Comment: Not necessary to change anything in WCMS if need meta tag on each page. Just have a custom item type and populate its data inside some view handler and you are done.

Comment: It's a bit more complex, I'm afraid, as the user should be able to set different meta tags against different pages or page templates - from backoffice or HMC.

Comment: If your requirement is to have different meta tags for different page then that the only long way to go. Creating a custom component and binding it to cms templates etc.